# Wrong use of JavaScript promise

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

**Edit:** It is reported that this question is the same as another mail in another thread. Not so; mine refers to specific code, the other is general.

---

I'm trying to implement a Promise for getValues (), I'm not referring to PromiseAll, but to the simple Promise of getValues. The problem is that "message" in getValues().then... is undefined so I believe that Promise is not doing its job, where is it wrong?

```
app.get('/inserisciDati',function(request, response){

    console.log("/inserisciDati");

    articolo = request.query.articolo;
    costo = request.query.costo;
    quantita = request.query.quantita;
    negozio = request.query.negozio;
    data = request.query.data;

    getValues().then(function(){

        console.log("message=" + message);

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PUT,POST,GET,DELETE,OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("X-Powered-By",' 3.2.1');
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
        // risposta alla pagina richiedente obbligatoria
        // se non si risponde la funzione app.get("inserisciDati" verrà chiamata continuamente
        response.writeHead(200, {'content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'});
        response.end(message);

    });

});

// recupera l'id articolo, l' id categoria dell'articolo e genera l' id per il nuovo inserimento
function getValues(){

    return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

        Promise.all([getIdArticolo(), getIdCategoria(), getLastId()]).then(function(values){

            idArticolo = values[0];
            idCategoria = values[1];
            nuovoId = values[2]+1;

            sql="INSERT INTO registro VALUES ('" + nuovoId + "','" + articolo + "','" + idCategoria + 
            "','" + idArticolo + "','" + costo + "','" + quantita + 
            "','" + negozio + "','" + data + "')";

            console.log("sql="+sql);

            connection.query(sql, function(err, result) {

                if(err)
                    message = ("error:"+ err);

                else
                    message = "OK";

            });

        });

        resolve();

    });

}
```

Comment: Your `connection.query` call is not chained with the outer Promise. Also, avoid the explicit Promise construction antipattern

Comment: which anti pattern are you referring to?

Comment: how should i behave with connection.query?

Comment: You did not convert the callback API to a Promise

Comment: it is right as this ? https://pastebin.com/Nu85wpLd

Comment: No, you're not converting the callback API to promises - please read the linked question

Comment: forgive me but what callback are you referring to?